# Why can't I synthesize this VHDL program?

Tags: vhdl

I am new at VHDL, and I am trying to do a Binary to BCD converter, I have serached on Internet and now I am trying to make my own to understand it and VHDL, here is my program:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity Binary_to_BCD is
--generic(n: integer := 2);
    Port ( data     : in unsigned (7 downto 0);
              bcdout : out unsigned (11 downto 0));
end Binary_to_BCD;

architecture Behavioral of Binary_to_BCD is
    -- Inicio el proceso de conversion
    begin
    convert : process (data) is
        variable i : integer := 0;
        variable bin : unsigned (7 downto 0) := data;
        variable bcd : unsigned (11 downto 0) := to_unsigned(0, 12);
        begin
        -- Repito por el numero de bits
        for i in 0 to 7 loop
            bcd := bcd sll 1;       -- Desplazo un lugar a la izquierda el BCD
            bcd(0) := bin(7);       -- Ingreso el nuevo bit al BCD
            bin := bin sll 1;       -- Desplazo el bit que saque antes a la izquierda

            -- Compruebo cada grupo de 4 bits del BCD, si se pasa de 4 le sumo 3
            if(bcd(11 downto 8) > "0101") then
                bcd(11 downto 8) := bcd(11 downto 8) + "0011";
            end if;

            if(bcd(7 downto 4) > "0101") then
                bcd(7 downto 4) := bcd(7 downto 4) + "0011";
            end if;

            if(bcd(3 downto 0) > "0101") then
                bcd(3 downto 0) := bcd(3 downto 0) + "0011";
            end if;

        end loop;
        bcdout := bcd;
    end process convert;
end Behavioral;
```

I get this error on line 66 which is `bcdout := bcd;`:

```
Signal 'bcdout' bcdout is at left hand side of variable assignment statement.
```

After reading on the web and books I used `unsigned` instead of `std_logic_vector` because I need to rotate bits and arithmetic operations but still it doesn't synthesize.

Tried changing `unsigned` to `integer` and `:=` to `<=` but nothing works. It should be something very stupid but I don't realize. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sorry, not native English :) Corrected.

Comment: If you change line 66 to `bcdout <= bcd;` (and don't change anything between unsigned and integer), what error do you get? The error message you show is due to using `:=` instead of `<=` and the file should compile after that fix. (I don't remember if tools can synthesize your code though - it doesn't follow a very "hardware-oriented" approach as Zhehao Mao points out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is the incorrect use of variable assignment `:=` instead of signal assignment `<=` for the `bcdout` signal - exactly as the error message and other answers point out.

However there is an underlying confusion about where you are in a VHDL process, that is not unusual when starting out - as revealed in the comments about functions.

A common approach to this confusion is to point out tht "VHDL is used for hardware design and not programming" that - while useful in some ways - can lead to artificially primitive and painfully low level uses of VHDL that are really holding it back.

Writing VHDL in a "software way" CAN work - and very well - however it does require a wider perspective on software AND hardware engineering than you can pick up through merely learning C.

The above code is probably synthesisable and will probably work - but it will almost certainly NOT do what you think it does. However a few small changes are in order rather than a completely different approach.

A couple of pointers may help :

the VHDL equivalent of a C function is a VHDL function.
the C equivalent of VHDL procedure is a void function.
(yes, C has procedures : it just calls them void functions to be contrary! :-)
the C equivalent of a VHDL process is ... a process. In other words, an entire C program as long as it doesn't use pthreads or fork/join.

And now you can see that VHDL is designed for parallel computation in a vastly more streamlined way than any dialect of C - processes are just building blocks, and signals are reliable forms of message passing or shared storage between processes.

So, within a process, you can (to a certain extent) think in software terms - but it is a HUGE mistake to think about "calling" a process as if it were a function.
Apologies if you've seen [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532) before but it will help understand the semantics of a VHDL process, and the use of signals between processes.

Now, as to the specific problems with your code:

1) It is asynchronous, i.e. unclocked. That means, guaranteeing how it responds to glitches on the input is ... difficult ... and knowing when the result is valid is harder than you need. Like uncontrolled use of global variables in C - not best practice!

So move to a clocked process for a safer, more analyzable design. This is also a step towards [increasing its speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765205/how-can-i-speed-up-my-math-operations-in-vhdl/14777458#14777458) later. But for now, think of a VHDL clocked process as an event loop or perhaps an interrupt handler in C. It wakes up when told to, executes in (effectively) zero time, and sleep()s until next time.

```
convert : process (clk) is
    variable bin : unsigned (7 downto 0);
    ...
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
       bin := data;
       for i in 0 to 7 loop
          ...
       end loop;
    end if;
    bcdout <= bcd;
end process convert;
```

2) the loops will be unrolled and generate a lot of hardware. This may not be a problem : it will deliver a result reasonably quickly (unlike the software equivalent!) There are ways to reduce the hardware use (state machines) or increase its speed (pipelining, link above) but they can wait for now...

3) This is actually the biggest problem with your original : your assignment of `data` to `bin` is actually a process variable *initialisation* not an assignment! It is only executed once, at t=0... And this is the most likely cause of any mis-operation you have seen.

The modified clocked example above assigns the latest `data` value every time the process is woken : i.e. every clock cycle, and is thus more likely to do what you want.

4) Minor niggle : your declaration of "i" is redundant and actually hidden by a new implicit "i" created by the loop statement. This implicit declaration is both safer and better than an explicit one because it takes its type explicitly from the loop bounds. Imagine what might happen with `for(int i; i<= 100000; i++)` when `int` is a 16-bit type...

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thank you for taking the time to explain this it really helped me :) Just a question about variable initialization, according to what I understood, the for loop will generate the hardware to execute all of this at the same time, so, the conversion will take only a clock right? When will be t=0 if the conversion is done instantly? Where I should declare `variable bin : unsigned (7 downto 0) := data;` if it has to be done at t=0?

Comment: t=0 at the very start of simulation! At which time your signal value is probably UUUU, i.e. uninitialised. Yes the conversion will only take one clock; the synth tool will advise you how long that clock cycle must be... Which means there will be a separate version of the "bcd" variable for each iteration of the loop, though (since you never keep `bcd` from one clock cycle to the next) they will be combinational wiring, not registers (storage), Probably only `bcdout` will appear as a register.

Comment: So I don't have to declare `variable bin : unsigned (7 downto 0) := data;` inside process. But if for example I declare it just below `architecture` I get an error related to shared variables.

Comment: No you MUST declare `variable bin : unsigned (7 downto 0);` inside the process (before `begin`). What doesn't work is initialising it, `:= data` there - you need the separate assignment. See the way my code sample (above) did it.

Comment: Hooo thank you! Everything makes sense now, so I have to rethink my program because on this way it is not working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Huh, strange. Have you tried making bcd a signal instead of a variable?

However, I think your main problem here is that you are trying to write VHDL in a "software" way, using a for loop and sequential logic. That is generally not the way you should write hardware descriptions. You should either use combinational logic, which involves concurrent assignment, or sequential logic, which involves doing things on the rising edge of the clock. It seems that what you are trying to implement is a combinational circuit. In that case, you should write separate concurrent assignments for each of your decimal digits. Take a look at http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/concurrent.html for some examples of concurrent signal assignments. You will probably want to use either selected or conditional signal assignment.

Comment: But isn't process intended to execute "instructions" in order? I mean, is a bad practice use process? Changing bcd to signal generates another error :/

Comment: No, that's not what the process statement is for. The process statement is usually used to perform sequential logic (logic tied to a clock edge). All the assignments inside are still concurrent, it's just that they will only change when the inputs in the sensitivity list change.

Comment: Hooo I think I understand it, according to this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70412/vhdl-convert-from-binary-integer-to-bcd-and-display-it-on-the-7-segment-displa I also based my code from http://vhdlguru.blogspot.ro/2010/04/8-bit-binary-to-bcd-converter-double.html but they use a function which execute sequential code right? That's why my code is not working.

Comment: No, they are doing the same thing as you are. The problem is that the for loop isn't sequential. Each part of the for loop (0 to 13) is running concurrently. Read the accepted answer for that question. It explains what I'm getting at pretty well.

Comment: Yes, `for loop` generate multiple instances of the hardware inside it, but in a `function` seems to works like in C or Java because, according to the answer the synthesis process is different for a function and for a process right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The VHDL in that question is using `process` and not `function`.

Comment: I refer to the web from which the design is based: http://vhdlguru.blogspot.ro/2010/04/8-bit-binary-to-bcd-converter-double.html

Answer (score 0):

bcdout is a signal, and you are using the variable assignment operator := with it

replace line

```
bcdout := bcd;
```

with

```
bcdout <= bcd;
```

I've not tried to compile to see if there are any other problems, but that should answer your question.